# Как вывести значения с множественного свойства инфоблока?

Tags: битрикс

Есть инфоблок - называется например `(Родитель)`. В родителе есть поле под названием `ID товара (в множественном списке) - ["PRODUCTS_ASSORTIMENT_ONENDER"]`.

Пытаюсь вывести все ID товаров через `GetList`.

```
    <?
     $arSelect2207 = Array("PROPERTY_PRODUCTS_ASSORTIMENT_ONENDER");
     $arFilter2207 = Array("IBLOCK_ID"=>47, "ID"=>27389, "ACTIVE"=>"Y");
     $res2207 = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter2207, false, Array("nTopCount2207"=>$result), $arSelect2207);

     while($ob2207 = $res2207->GetNextElement()) {
          $arFields2207 = $ob2207->GetFields();
          print_r($arFields2207);
     }
    ?>
```

Выводит всего одно значение то, есть один ID `26048` !

```
[PROPERTY_PRODUCTS_ASSORTIMENT_ONENDER_VALUE] => 26048
[~PROPERTY_PRODUCTS_ASSORTIMENT_ONENDER_VALUE] => 26048
[PROPERTY_PRODUCTS_ASSORTIMENT_ONENDER_VALUE_ID] => 218663
```

Хотя было указанно не один id а несколько `26048`, `26049`, `26045`.

В чем может быть причина ?

Выводил значения в карточке товара по такому способу - выводила все ID, а сейчас вывожу в карточке товара только ID беру теперь с другого инфоблока и значение только одно выводится!

> Получил все ID через `GetNext()`. Но у меня реализованно через
>   `GetList()` - вывод остальных полей инфоблока.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в фильтре отбора элементов указан параметр ID элемента `"ID"=>27389`. Уберите его чтобы получать все элементы.

Вам нужно привести строку к такому виду - 
`$arFilter2207 = Array("IBLOCK_ID"=>47, "ACTIVE"=>"Y");`

Comment: Ведь у меня и так написанно `$arFilter2207 = Array("IBLOCK_ID"=>47, "ID"=>27389, "ACTIVE"=>"Y");`

Comment: прошу прощения опечатался,  `"ID"=>27389` надо убрать. поправил текст.

Comment: `"IBLOCK_ID"` - это получается у меня `ID` инфоблока, `"ID"` - это `ID` элемента инфоблока.  А вот `"PROPERTY_PRODUCTS_ASSORTIMENT_ONENDER"` этот параметр передает массив `ID` - которые должен получить, но получаю всего только 1 элемент массива - тоесть первый `ID` с массива! А вот `ID` которое говорите убрать - у меня `ID` менятся в зависимости какой `ID` укажет человек в каталоге - в карточке товара ! :)

Comment: @МаксимСиваконь множественное поле с каким типом, можете написать? Тогда смогу дать вам пример по работе с множественным свойством.

Comment: Тип - `список` или `привязка к элементам` ( множ. )